# Find min of several columns in matlab without for loop

Tags: matlab

I have got a matrix `M` with `R` rows and `C*k` columns. I want to create another matrix `F` with `R` rows and `C` columns, so that

```
 F(:,j) = min(M(:,(j-1)*k+1:j*k),[],2)
```

In other words first column of `F` should be min of first `k` columns of `M`.

Second column of `F` should be min of second `k` columns of `M` and so on.
I am trying to reshape matrix `M` to `R*C x k` matrix `D` find min and reshape it again to `R x C` matrix.But I cannot properly reshape `M` to `F`, so that `F(i, :) = M(b, (j-1)*k+1:j*k)`

Here is a small example:

```
k=2;
M = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12;];
then
F = [1 3; 5 7; 9 11];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to reshape it to an `R x k x (C / k)` matrix and then compute the `min` along the second dimension and  then squeeze the result to remove the now-empty second dimension.

```
F = squeeze(min(reshape(M, size(M, 1), k, size(M, 2)/k), [], 2))
```